# Batch file to delete all text files in a folder over 10 days old except certain ones

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm new to batch files, trying to write one that will delete all .txt files in a folder over 10 days old EXCEPT one called template.txt. How is this done?  I have the below but it deletes ALL txt files over 10 days.  Appreciate your help.

```
forfiles /p "C:\test" /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c del @path" /d -10
```

Comment: `attrib +r template.txt` before and `attrib -r template.txt` after. Setting a file to read only prevents it from deleting.

Comment: `forfiles /p "C:\test" /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c if /I not @file==0x22template.txt0x22 del @path" /d -10`

Comment: @Squashman that didn't work, deletes the template.txt file

Comment: I just fixed the code.  I forgot that you need to use the hex codes for the quotes.

Comment: @Squashman That did the trick with updated code! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the contition into the command line run by [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), like this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\test" /M "*.txt" /D -10 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if /I not @file==0x22template.txt0x22 del @path"
```

The `if @isdir==FALSE` part is to exclude any directories from being processed further in case there are some with `.txt` at the end of their names (although quite unlikely), because `forfiles` enumerates both files and directories.

`if /I not @file==0x22template.txt0x22` becomes `if /I not "<name of currently iterated item>"=="template.txt"` and excludes files named `template.txt` from being deleted. The `/I` option makes the comparison case-insensitive, like Windows also treats file and directory paths.